# Adding space between text and footnote rule

Tags: footnotes

How I can change the distance between the text and footnote rule in this example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\addtolength{\footskip}{22mm}
\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3mm\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@
  \kern 3mm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{Footnote example}
\kant[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the option footnotesep, at best (like the default) with a bit shrink and stretch:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm,
         left=20mm,right=20mm,heightrounded,
         footnotesep=3cm plus 4pt minus 4pt %<--- change to a suitable value
         ]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\addtolength{\footskip}{22mm}
\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3mm\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@
  \kern 3mm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{Footnote example}
\kant[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was unaware that the `geometry` package has this option. It seems unrelated to the rest of what the package does, namely dealing with placement of the text block, headers, footers and margin paragraphs on the page. I would have just set `\footnotesep` directly instead.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen `\footnotesep` is for the space *after* the line, before the line is `\skip\footins`. And footnotes are in an insert so it is not completly outside geometries dealings.

Comment: Ah, my bad. But then, the name `footnotesep` for the option is a rather confusing one. And footnotes go *inside* the text block, which is why it didn't seem to me to belong. AFAICT, spaces surrounding figures and tables are not adjustable via the geometry package, and they seem to belong in the same category.

Comment: I tried footnotesep=7mm and it works fine. Also footnotesep doesnt seem to put distance to my second set of footnotes. But I get a bad box.

Comment: Give footnotesep a bit shrink and stretch:         `footnotesep=7mm plus 4pt minus 4pt`

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestions by Ulrike Fischer and David Carlisle I increased \skip\footins with `\setlength{\skip\footins}{5mm}` :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\setlength{\skip\footins}{5mm} %<------------ add this
\def\footnoterule{
\kern-3mm \hrule width 2in \kern -.4pt 
\kern 3mm} 

\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{Footnote example}
\kant[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the geometry option? It does exactly the same.

Comment: I thought footnotesep adds space around a footnote set (I have two), and \footskip for some reason isnt working when I run it.

Comment: Didn't you try my example? And why didn't you comment it if you think it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Sorry. I did try it, but probably am doing something wrong. At first the distance was very big, like in your image, than after I disabled footnotesep, changing \addtolength{\footskip}{5mm} didnt modify anything. Sorry for not commenting on that.

Comment: Well I used `footnotesep=3cm` for the demo, so yes this gives a large space. Change the `3cm` to whatever value you need.